# Darle formato a la salida de System() en C

Tags: c, windows, formato

Simplemente tengo un ascci art que muestro con diferentes printfs y quiero poner en el medio el nombre del usuario . (con el nombre me refiero al user de windows).

Pense en sacar el nombre con un System("whoami"), lo que me funciona de perfeccion pero al no poder almacenarlo en una variable no le puedo dar formato y cuando pongo el system y el comando a pelas, automaticamente luego de poner el user imprime un salto de lineas.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como manipularlo o como sacar el username de una manera diferente seria de gran ayuda.

Resumiendo especificaciones:

Lenguaje C . (Solo C no c++ ni nada por el estilo)

Sistema operativo (Windows)

Problema especifico:
El problema se me da cuando intento imprimir en pantalla el nombre de usuario en medio de muchos caracteres, y con el System("Whoami") me imprime el nombre pero hace un salto de linea automatico luego del nombre.

Posibles soluciones pensadas :
Claramente no tengo una solucion pero pensaba en alguna forma de poder almacenar esto con algo similar a un System() en una variable ya que con el system no se puede o alguna forma de darle formato para establecer que no haga el salto de linea.

```
        printf("***********************************************************************\n");   
printf("|                                       %s             |\n",string1); //user , String1
   printf (" ---------------------------------------------------------------------\n"); 

System("whoami");
```

Como pueden ver en el codigo quiero que el resultado del whoami vaya antes de la variable string1 pero en la misma linea que el String1 ya que es muy importante mantener el formato porque en la parte de abajo hay una parte de ascci estetico.

Comment: agrega lo que llevas hecho

Comment: Lo he agregado pero no hay mucho codigo que aclarar simplemente con el system whoami se hace un salto de linea que no quiero que ocurra porque necesito poner otra variable seguida del whoami es decir en la misma linea y no puedo almacenar en una variable el resutlado de un comando system entonces estoy contra la espada y la pared

Comment: Con `system()` no puedes capturar la salida. Investiga el uso de `popen()` en su lugar (es mucho más farragoso, pero tienes más control y puedes capturar entrada/salida del subproceso)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `system` retorna `int`, y lo que hace es darle el control a otro fragmento software *(A traves de la shell del sistema)* el cual está fuera de tu control, de igual forma le otorga el control de `stdin`, `stdout` y `stderr` para mostrar y/o pedir datos a través de los mismos streams que tiene tu app *(No comprobado, pero debe ser así)*.

Asignar el valor arrojado por el comando `whoami` llamado desde [`system(const char *);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) es una tarea algo tediosa, pero no imposible.

Si lo que quieres hacer es imprimir el valor de la variable de entorno `$USER`<sup>1</sup>, te recomiendo usar [`getenv(const char *);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html), dicha función se utiliza para retornar el valor de las variables de entorno como una cadena de texto (`char *`) que tu programa puede utilizar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char *valorVariable = getenv("USER");
  if (valorVariable)
    printf("La variable de entorno $USER tiene el valor: '%s'.\n", valorVariable);
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "Error! No pude encontrar la variable de entorno $USER\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Ya con esto dicho, puedes agregarlo a tu ASCII Art:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char *currentUser = getenv("USER");
  if (currentUser) {
    printf("************************\n");
    printf("| %20s |\n", currentUser); // Esto es una prueba.
    printf("************************\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Al correr el fragmento de código puesto arriba recibo la siguiente salida *(Desde un IDE online que opera con ubuntu)*:

```
************************
|               ubuntu |
************************
```

<sup>De ahí en adelante, posicionarlo en el medio es cuestión de matemáticas y otras cosas.</sup>

Saludos :)

<sup>1: Hasta donde sé, la variable de entorno `$USER` sólo está disponible en linux *(Y MacOS, creo)*, para Windows deberías usar `USERNAME`.</sup>